# Comparing difference scores between 2 groups over 2 conditions

Tags: repeated-measures, group-differences

I am investigating a common discrepancy between male and female self-reports on a survey about sexual experiences.  Generally, women report ~2/3 higher rates then men do.  I have modified the survey and now need to find out if/how the discrepancy between males' and females' reporting rates may have changed.  Males and Females each fill out both verisons (modified and original) of there gender-specific survey.  So, what i want to compare is the difference between male-and-female difference scores on the original survey, and male-and-female differences on the newer/modified survey.  What specific statistical test could I use here?

Comment: It depends on your design, of which there aren't enough details. ... e.g. was the order of the two surveys randomized? Or were the particpants assigned by design to either a survey 1 first or a survey 2 first treatment sequence? ... Or did everyone do one first and then the other?

Comment: the order of the two surveys was not randomized.  each participant took the original version of the survey first, based on gender.

Comment: furthermore, my samples are not matched, so i have an uneven number of males and females.